# Python Class __init__ syntax error

Tags: python, initialization

```
from game_state import GameState
class TippyGameState(GameState):
    def __init__(self, p, interactive=False, current_total = 0):
        GameState.__init__(self, p)
        if interactive:
                self.size = int(input('Map size?')
                self.current_total = self.size * self.size
        self.size = 3
        self.over = (current_total < 1)
```

When I run this in terminal, it always shows a syntax error from `self.current_total = self.size * self.size` to the end, can someone tell me why?

Comment: See the `{}` button on the toolbar? It *formats code for you*. No need to muck with `&nbsp;` or backslashes or extra spaces at the ends of lines. :-)

Comment: You forgot to close the `input()` call, missing a `)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
self.size = int(input('Map size?')
```

to

```
self.size = int(input('Map size?'))
```

Answer (score 0):

In such a case try looking at the previous line.
replace `self.size = int(input('Map size?')` by `self.size = int(input('Map size?'))`